# Recording video's with two cameras?

Tags: video, camera, sync, post-production

I have started to make some videos and I want to add a second camera to get a different angle.

The main camera I have is a Nikon D7200.

I am looking at a secondary camera, but I am hesitant because I want the video's to look the same, in that color and tone are the same and not obviously shot on two different cameras.

I am also, on a budget and would like to stay in it if possible. I know the D5500 has the same sensor as the D7200, so it would probably be the same in terms of color and tone, but would a different sensor really be that bad?

How do you guys match up two dissimilar cameras, to not make it look wierd, or is that not really a concern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've had my fair share of matching. C100 with 5D MK III, 5D MK III with 7D, 7D with C100, 7D with a Sony Camcorder.

It's all a matter of getting two cameras that are similar in terms of resolution and how 'soft' the image is. For example, the C100 is incredibly sharp, like 4k sharp in 1080p, whereas the DSLRS I mentioned are quite soft. Although you can add sharpening, it doesn't have the same feel and really gives you the idea that two cameras were used.

That being said, staying with a DSLR within the same camera company means that the baked in color profile should be relatively consistent. The sharpness on the other hand my not be, but with DSLR's you'll never get really sharp images (excluding the GH4 and A7S) so I would say go for it.

You might see some subtle difference in color tone. Some casting more or less of a certain color in the exact same environment which is an easy fix with some general color correction. I'm willing to bet if you make a color correction present using footage shot in a consistent test environment you can make your workflow much faster. Its just a matter of watching your scopes for consistency. It helps if you use a similar lens, focal length, subject (go with a person you want to match skintones), and lighting setup (tungsten) for these tests.

Some color correction info another one of my answers: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/15998/10619

Comment: why do DSLR's not make sharp images?

Comment: http://3d.coldstreams.com/?p=383 applies to any dslr, with some a7s and gh4 (even gh3) being really good at resolving sharpness from their sensors

Comment: What would you think if I paired up the D7200 with a Nikon 1 J5?

Comment: @JonYork I cant speak to the quality of either of those cameras. I do not shoot with Nikon, but I was merely speaking generally about DSLRs. Personally, I'd suggest getting GH4 if you are looking into a budget solution. Its a micro 4/3 camera, but they have adaptors that will allow your Nikon glass to work on it. http://www.metabones.com/products/details/MB_SPNFG-m43-BM1